# Is there a way I can get the line items in stripe synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this function

```
async function getLineItems(session_id) {
    var lineItems = []
    await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
        `${session_id}`,
        function(err, data) { // this function is called asynchronously, but I need it synchronous
            lineItems = data.data
        }
    )
    
    return lineItems // this is called before i get the data
}
```

And I need to somehow make the function in `stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems` synchronous.
Or somehow return `lineItems` after the function is called. Right now the function returns an empty array every time.

Comment: You're using asynchronous code improperly, listLineItems is a callback in this case. return lineItems will call before listLineItems finishes.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's what I'm  trying to solve.

Comment: Okay, so what's the main scope look like before you call getLineItems()? Unsure what lineItems is for just yet, so need more context. Just to avoid callback hell.

Comment: I have a get request in which I call this function.

Comment: Okay so are you sending this data directly to user when it's finished? Show the function calling this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `await` keyword you could assign the return value of the fulfilled promised to variable like so :

```
async function getLineItems(session_id) {
  try{
    const lineItems = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(`${session_id}`)
    return lineItems.data;
  } catch(e){
    //handle error
  }
}
```

Since `listLineItems` is a paginated API I would strongly recommend using [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) to collect all the lineItems like so

```
async function getLineItems(session_id) {
  try{
    const lineItems = [];
    for await (const lineItem of stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(`${session_id}`)) {
      lineItems.push(lineItem);
    }
    return lineItems;
  } catch(e){
    //handle error
  }
}
```